# Saving Resize Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, resize

This is what i have,

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        string b = textBox1.Text;
        string a = textBox2.Text;
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        f2.button8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(x, y);
        f2.Show();
    }
```

this code was able to change the button size on the other form.. the problem is, once the applciation is closed and re open .. the size of button8 back to its default size ..

what i wanted to do is once the button is resize it will be  its default size. And even if the application is closed and re open, the new size will be saved..

can someone help me here.. THANKS!

Comment: store size in a configuration file

Comment: you should use a settings-file for this. Store your x and y parameters there if changed and load them on startup...

Answer (score 4):

When you change it you're just changing it in 'real time', and the memory has no recollection of those changes once the memory has essentially expired; when you reload the application you're reloading it from the initial state in which is was deployed.

You can use [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) to overcome this, storing the values of the size of the button when the size is changed, and loading the values from there the next time the application is ran.

Comment: how exactly can  i do this?

Comment: @JurelJacinto Are you familiar with the settings API, and did you read the link I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Just save size of button on other form into app.config by catching SizeChanged event.

There's example - http://sdrv.ms/11BSi2L

Comment: how exactly can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Like they said, store it in `Application Settings`

From `Project Properties`, create a `Settings`, let example `ButtonSize`

[image]

This [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/11/28/497792.aspx) is for `Form Size` and `Form Location` but you have a guide now for your solution.